# Output showing System.Windows.Form.Label after every word

Tags: c#

I am having a problem where the user enters his inputs into a text box (like a name). If the name is Jim Bob it will output like Jim System.Windows.Form.Label Bob System.Windows.Form.Label. I searched the properties tab and I am following along from the book but they do not have the same problem I have. I added some code below but I don't think it has anything to do with the problem.

```
string output;
output = textBoxPrefT.Text + ". " + textBoxFirstN + " " + textBoxMiddleN + " " + textBoxLastN;
labelOutput.Text = output;
```

Comment: `output = textBoxPrefT.Text + ". " + textBoxFirstN.Text + " " + textBoxMiddleN.Text + " " + textBoxLastN.Text;`

Comment: You have an integrated debugger - use it. breakpoint on the line and inspect your variables. You'll see that these are System.Windows.Form.Label. If you print them they use theire .ToString() and thats is printing its type() - why you would like to print the labels text eludes me though.....

Comment: also why are your labels named textBox ???

Comment: They aren't labels, they are text boxes for a user input

Comment: `Jim System.Windows.Form.Label Bob System.Windows.Form.Label` .... why is this then printing `Label` ?

Comment: I ment to put .Textbox I must have been looking at the labels right next to them my bad : /

Comment: Next time around, please copy&pate your errors verbatim - word for word- exactly as given. Helps to solve your problems kindof better... anybody findog _your_ question on SO search could get very confused if question, problem and solution are handling different things alltogether because of wrong information given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include `.Text` for all textboxes so it should look like this

```
string output;
output = textBoxPrefT.Text + ". " + textBoxFirstN.Text + " " + textBoxMiddleN.Text + " " + textBoxLastN.Text;
labelOutput.Text = output;
```

Comment: How did I miss that, i even have it for the first one but none of the others. Thank you

Comment: 5 minutes earlier and this would have been an ingenious answer. Now it looks like you read my comment and wanted to confirm it.